# How to scrape the content on different tabs from this website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the synonyms of words from Thesaurus.com (using bs4 and requests). An example page: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/put?s=t
The problem I'm running into is that there are three different tabs for different meanings of the word, and each one has a different list of synonyms. I want to scrape them all, but I'm not sure how to access the synonyms listed in the non-active tab. When I print the soup'd html and ctrl+f, the synonyms from the non-primary tab don't seem to be in the html at all, which seems to indicate to me that I cannot just simply scrape the page once. Anyway, what's the easiest way to get these other synonyms?

EDIT: 
As requested by a comment, here is my code to scrape a word currently. This code works perfectly, as I said; I just can't figure out how to scrape from the other tabs on the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


results = {}
def scrape_word(word): 
    url = baseURL + word
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    if (response.status_code == 404):
        results[word] = []
        return
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    # Look only at the main content div or else you'll get other undesired tags
    soup = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'css-1kc5m8x e1qo4u830'})
    # The below variable is the class used by Thesaurus.com for synonyms
    word_class = 'css-133coio etbu2a32'
    # Structure of site is spans hold links which have text of the word
    spanList = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': word_class})
    synList = [span.find('a').text for span in spanList]
    results[word] = synList
```

EDIT2: a comment by cddt has given me an alternative route to the data I desire, but if anyone knows, I'm still curious how I could've solved the problem without his solution.

Comment: Please add your code to the question using [edit].

Comment: Have you checked the tag in the page source which begins with `<script>window.INITIAL_STATE = {...`? Seems like it contains the data you are looking for in a nice JSON.

Comment: @cddt thank you so much! You've helped me immensely. If I might ask, how did you find that? Surely you didn't just scroll through the source code?

Comment: I checked the source code, and used `ctrl + F` to search for words in the visible and hidden tabs. I was expecting to find some javascript which called another resource when you click on the tab, but instead I found it was already pre-loaded.
If it was reliant on some javascript, I would have advised you to use `selenium` to scrape the web page. It is a little bit more fiddly to use, but lets you execute events such as mouse clicks to trigger scripts which can update the display. See: https://pypi.org/project/selenium/